# What is the second argument in ArrayAdapter() constructor?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#FillingTheLayout

In these docs, we have this snippet:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myStringArray);
```

It is then said that the second argument of the constructor is "The layout that contains a `TextView` for each string in the array." What does this mean? What is meant by a "layout"? How can such a Layout exist when my array could be of any size? What is this layout used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is meant by a "layout"?

It is referring to a layout resource. Layout resources are covered in [the page that you linked to](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout).

> What is this layout used for?

It will be used for rows in your `ListView`, or cells in your `GridView`, or other things depending on what `AdapterView` you use with your `ArrayAdapter`.

> How can such a Layout exist when my array could be of any size?

The layout resource will be used to provide the UI for a single item out of the array. As needed, your `ArrayAdapter` will create `ListView` rows using the layout resource. Think of it as a template for what an individual row in your list looks like.

Answer (score 0):

This is about how you organize your items(say of a ListView). You have to pass the name of the xml file as the second argument which will describe whether you want the list items to be showed in textArea, tableView etc.